# Enabling Protected Users on Windows 2019 AD prevents users from logging in

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2019, users

Our Windows Server 2019 AD is setup and working well.
Due to the Outlook exploit (CVE-2023-23397), we implemented one of the recommendations - move users to the Protected Users group.
Since then, users have been having issues to login on their laptop from home.

They use a username/password combo and in the office it works fine, but once they get home - none of the passwords (password/PIN/facelock) will work.

Is there a way around this?
I see I am logged in on my laptop using Kerberos, not NTLM.

Kind regards,
Tom

Comment: Hi Tom, did you find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 4):

Protected Users is not for regular users. It is for the most privileged user accounts. Remove the regular user accounts from the Protected Users group.

Answer (score 1):

Members of the protected users group will require a domain controller connection to log in. No cached logon will be allowed. It is possible your users at home rely on cached credentials (logon type 11).

There are a number of new event Id's to help troubleshoot documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/credentials-protection-and-management/protected-users-security-group

Answer (score 0):

Please indicate if you are aware that a patch is available: https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/vulnerability/CVE-2023-23397 at the bottom, you find the download links.